# Accessing a form control inside a group box on the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have about 100 form control checkboxes on a sheet and have no problem getting to and saving their values. Those are not contained within any group boxes. However, I want to access a specific checkbox that is located inside a group box and that checkbox does not have a meaningful name. I would expect that I could first locate the group, then isolate the checkbox.

How do I loop within a group box, when not on a userform sheet?

I think I have to use `.Range(array())` or `.Groupitems()` but I can't seem to make it work.

A way to capture that checkbox (that is located inside a group), while looping through all the checkboxes on mysheet would also be ok since I already do this to save their values.

```
For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
        If sh.FormControlType = xlGroupBox Then
            mygroup = sh.name
            'need to loop within "mygroup" and find the checkbox
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FYI groupbox is also called a frame in VBA. Suppose you put all the checkboxes in groupbox called `myGB`.

```
For each cb in UserForm1.myGB.controls
   cb.Value = True
   ....
Next cb
```

Comment: Jeanno. Your suggestion applies to ActiveX controls on userforms. Mine however are form controls inserted ditrectly on the sheet. Those are handled differently.